# magento 2 generate coupon code based on a rule programmatically

Tags: magento, magento2

I have a rule created in Magento 2, e.g. 10% OFF, this rule uses auto generated coupon code, instead of a pre-assigned code.

I'd like to know how I can generate codes based on the rule programmatically.

NOTE: This is not about creating a new rule programmatically. I want to generate codes based on a existing rule, so I can add more codes when needed but doesn't have to create a new rule every time, e.g. when a customer subscribes our mailing list, I can execute the code to generate a new code under the same rule and send it to the subscriber.

I found this post, but this is about creating a new rule;

https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/207311/magento2-2-programmatically-create-coupon

I found the solution for Magento 1:

https://mage2-blog.com/magento-1-programmatically-create-promotion-coupon-codes/

Thanks

Comment: Right now you've kind of given us a spec, some possibly related code, and asked us to do your coding - and that's not how this site works. You need to digest the links you've provided and then present us with the code that you want to try, letting us know what is and isn't working and how you want it to work. We can then help you fix your code.

Comment: Check Article with details, https://www.rakeshjesadiya.com/create-coupon-code-programmatically-magento-2/

Answer (score 4):

It is actually easier than I thought. Code below worked for me:

```
$couponGenerator = $objectManager->create('Magento\SalesRule\Model\CouponGenerator');

    $data = array(
      'rule_id' => $rule->getId(),
      'qty' => '1',
      'length' => '12',
      'format' => 'alphanum',
      'prefix' => 'pre',
      'suffix' => 'suf',
    );

    $codes = $couponGenerator->generateCodes($data);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Coupon based on the Sales rule id.
You first need to Sales rule with basic details like Rule name, description, Rule type, website ids and Customer type.

[Create Coupon Rule Programmatically Magento 2](https://www.rakeshjesadiya.com/create-coupon-code-programmatically-magento-2/)

Refer above tutorials for more details.